# Export DataGridView to Excel File missing row

Tags: vb.net, excel, export-to-excel

i used this code to export datagridview to excel but always miss one row and if datagridview return single row the excel return just the titles without the single row 
the export code is

```
Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
        Dim I, j, iC As Short
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Try
            Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
            Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
            xlApp.Visible = True

            rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            With excelWorksheet
                .Cells.Select()
                .Cells.Delete()
                For iC = 0 To colsTotal
                    .Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
                Next
                For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
                    For j = 0 To colsTotal
                        .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
                    Next j
                Next I
                .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 12

                .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
                .Cells.Select()
                .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
                .Cells(1, 1).Select()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            'RELEASE ALLOACTED RESOURCES
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
            xlApp = Nothing
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i found the answer.
the answer is to delete -1 from

```
For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
  For j = 0 To colsTotal
     .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
  Next j
Next I
```

to be

```
For I = 0 To rowsTotal 
      For j = 0 To colsTotal
         .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
      Next j
    Next I
```